# How to add buttons for macro by using xlwings or pywin32

Tags: python, python-3.x, vba, pywin32, xlwings

I'd like to know how to add buttons for macro by using `xlwings` or `pywin32`.
I found the way for shape objects(execute `test("shape")`), but `test("button")` failed because of no-attribute error in`sheet1.api.Buttons.Add`.

I simply implemented following because when I add a button manually in excel recording macro, I found `ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(288, 44.25, 151.5, 32.25).Select` in VBA editor.

```py
import xlwings as xw
def test_button(obj_type):
    
    wb = xw.books.add()
    wb.save("test.xlsm")
    
    sheet1 = wb.sheets["Sheet1"]
    
    if obj_type == "shape":
        # Add Shape
        sheet1.api.Shapes.AddShape(1, 100, 50, 150, 30)
        
        shape_names = []
        for shape in sheet1.shapes:
            if shape.name not in shape_names:
                shape_names.append(shape.name)
                shape.characters.api.Text = "Shape Name = {}".format(shape.name)
                shape.api.OnAction = "sample_sub"
        print("shape names list:")
        print(shape_names)
    elif obj_type == "button":
        button = sheet1.api.Buttons.Add(288, 44.25, 151.5, 32.25) # FIXME
        button.api.OnAction = "sample_sub" # FIXME
        button.api.Text = "sample button" # FIXME
    else:
        raise ValueError("Invalid obj_type : {}".format(obj_type))
    
    return wb
```

`sample_sub` is difined by :

```py
@xw.sub
def sample_sub():
    wb = xw.Book.caller()
    sheet1 = wb.sheets["Sheet1"]
    sheet1.range("A1").value = "This is a test message."
```

Comment: I don't have any attributes under 'sheet.Button' for pywin32. You could try raise an issue with xlwings, see https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/missing_features.html

Answer (score 0):

According to MS documentation, there is no object named Buttons.
You can create a button using
[FormControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.shapes.addformcontrol), e.g. `sheet.api.Shapes.AddFormControl(0,1,1,1,1)`, See [xlformcontrol enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlformcontrol).